Exponential Cosine Gaussian Integral
through the course of some computations I've come across this integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{a \cos(t) - b t^2} dt \qquad a,b \in \mathbb{R}, \quad b>0
$$
which is by far the simplest (looking) form of my problem I can find.
I have been unsuccessful at evaluating it, or getting a way get a hold on it.
I am looking for a closed form expression that avoids an infinite sum or integral.

Do you have any reason to believe that this admits an elementary closed form?

maybe some kind of large $a$ or large $b$ asymptotics?

Treating b as a non-negative real variable, one can do the Laplace transform of our integral I(b) and obtain $\mathcal{L}_b(I)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{s}}e^{a\text{cosh}\sqrt{s}}$ (not arccosh, mind you). I didn't give much thought about the inverse yet.

A long comment. We have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{a\cos t-b t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\frac{a}{2}e^{it}}e^{\frac{a}{2}e^{-it}}e^{-b t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a/2)^{m+n}}{m!n!} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i(m-n)t}e^{-b t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}} \sum_{m,n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a/2)^{m+n}}{m!n!} e^{-(m-n)^2/4b} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(a/2)^{m+n}}{m!n!} e^{-(m-n)^2/4b} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}} \sum_{\nu=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\nu^2/4b} \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(a/2)^{2m+\nu}}{m!(m+\nu)!} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}} \sum_{\nu=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\nu^2/4b} I_{\nu}(a),
\end{align*}
where $I_{\nu}(a)$ denotes the modified Bessel function of the first kind. (In the fourth step and thereafter, we are also using the convention that $\frac{1}{z!} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(z+1)}$, which defines an entire function on all of $\mathbb{C}$ that vanshes for negative integers $z = -1, -2, \ldots$)
However, I have no idea whether this will reduce to a closed form or not.

Funnily enough this is the form I started with, since it has a sum with the summing variable as the order of the modified Bessel functions I was trying to avoid this form.
